# Github API: how to find the branches of a pull request?

Tags: github, github-api

The Github API (v3) allows you to get a listing of pull requests, and get more details on an individual pull request. What I can't seem to find is the name of the branch the pull request is coming from and the branch the pull request is suggesting the code be merged into.

Using the Github API how do you determine the branches involved in a pull request?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

1. **Access a Pull Request URL.**  Let's use https://api.github.com/repos/github/gitignore/pulls/566 as an example.
2. **Parse the JSON object.**

---

A Pull Request references two branches.  The `base` branch is the merge target. Usually this is the `master` branch of the repository.

> - `base.label` is `github:master`, meaning it's the `master` branch for > `github/gitignore`.
> - `base.ref` is the branch name "master".
> - `base.sha` is the current **SHA** of that branch.

The `head` branch is what you're merging into the `base`.

> - `head.label` is `fidelski:add-obvious-autotools-files`, meaning it's the `add-obvious-autotools-files` branch for `fidelski/gitignore`.
> - `head.ref` is the branch name `add-obvious-autotools-files`.
> - `head.sha` is the current **SHA** of that branch.

Comment: I have found that `base.sha` can be a commit on the base branch which is newer than the `git merge-base`, yet older than the current head of that branch, by about a day, even for a PR which has not been touched in longer than that. Perhaps it gets periodically updated to the base branch head but is then cached for a while?

Comment: Yep, @JesseGlick is right, `base.sha` cannot be trusted. If you're doing anything that relies on the base branch current sha, get it direct.

Comment: Using the PyGithub API, I found I could get the branch name using `pr.head.label` where `pr` is my PullRequest object returned from `Repository.get_pull`