# Reading Base branch and Feature branch information from a github pull request by using batch file

Tags: git, github, github-api, pull-request

I need to read the base branch name and feature branch name via batch file.
i am new to this and have no idea about github pull request command line operations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github API: how to find the branches of a pull request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096331/github-api-how-to-find-the-branches-of-a-pull-request)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub-api%5D+pull+request